# Cheap development board for Windows CE

Tags: windows-ce, windows-embedded

I'm looking for a development board for WinCE, preferably with the following connectors:

- VGA/DVI for screen
- USB for kb/mouse
- Ethernet (10Mbit is OK, 100 would be even better ;-) )
- Storage (eg: SD/MMC/CF cards)

I'm looking for this, because I want to attend the Imagine Cup , Embedded Systems design. And I'm looking for a challenge, ofcourse ;-).

I found a board called HawkBoard (http://www.hawkboard.org), but I want to know if there are alternatives for about the same price (max $200 incl. shipping/customs/taxes). I need the BSP, ofcourse ;-).

Thanks!

Yvan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [eBox 2300/3300](http://www.compactpc.com.tw/ebox-3300.htm) is a low cost device that has been used for past Imagine Cup challenges.  It's x86, comes with a BSP, is in an enclosure, is low cost ([$195](http://www.wdlsystems.com/modperl/view_services.cgi?r=detail&prod_num=1EB23SK&aisle_id=1061) or [$255](http://www.wdlsystems.com/modperl/view_services.cgi?r=detail&prod_num=1EB33WE&aisle_id=1060)) and meets most of your needs.

Of course CE has forever shipped with a reference BSP for x86, so you can usually get just about any x86 device working, though most other devices tend to be pretty big physically.

There are also open source CE BSPs available for the [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.codeplex.com/) and [GumStix](http://gumstix.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 3):

The [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) is a good ARM system that costs $150. It has all the features you want, from the [product page](http://beagleboard.org/hardware):

- DVI-D for connecting digital computer monitors
- Compatibility with a huge collection of USB peripherals including hubs, keyboards, mice, WiFi, Bluetooth, web cameras, and much more
- MMC+/SD/SDIO interface for memory or wireless connectivity
- S-Video out for connecting your NTSC or PAL television or wearable visor
- Stereo audio in and out for a microphone and headphones or speakers
- Power via typical USB chargers for cell phones from your laptop, from an automobile adapter, from batteries, or even from a solar backpack

I never tried Windows CE myself, but a google search suggests it's possible, and there's even a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CJSLK5IJqO8) on YouTube.

Another option is [Gumstix](http://gumstix.net/), and there's a [project](http://gumstix.codeplex.com/) on codeplex to help you get Windows CE on it.

Comment: And is there an european reseller for the BeagleBoard? Gumstix is not quite an option, since CE support is experimental from what I've read.

Comment: I wouldn't say Gumstix's version of CE is any more "experimental" than that for Beagleboard.  The guys at Special Computing have created and Codeplexed BSPs for both.  THe biggest challenge with Gumstix is that they seme to constantly change the hardware, even withing a revision, and don't tell anyone so it's anyone's guess if it will fit mechanically or have the exact same parts from shipment to shipment.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it also depends if you want to start something for fun or rather serious.

Check some of the big manufacturers homepages too, so you can see what specifications could
help the realisation of your ideas or set limits to them.

What helps for shure is if you choose a platform, that can be configured easily and its much more fun if you start with something that can work out of the box too.

Here an example, like you can find it on a lot of manufactureres homepages on the web.

http://www.toradex.com/En/Products/Colibri

Colibri modules feature state of the art technology, and aimed at low power systems that require high CPU performance. They are equipped withall the interfaces needed in a modern embedded device.

Colibri T20　features include:
·        Dual Core ARM Cortex A9 Processor
·        2 x 1.0GHz Processor Speed
·        Full HD 1080p Video (Encode / Decode)
·        Powerful 3D Rendering Performance
·        True Dual Display
·        Up to 12 Megapixel Camera Sensor Support

And if this is to much there are Colibri modules in the family which are in a lower price range with adapted specifications that might fit you needs better.

What I personally think is important, that you know that you can get good support and talk to the right people in person as well.

Give it a shot and good luck.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Any old PC that has a video adapter that is VESA compliant and a network adapter based on NE2000, realtek RTL8139 or 3COm 3Cx5 can be used as Windows CE target device using the CEPC BSP.
If you have an old 486 or more powerful PC lying unused somewhere in your garage, it's time to resurrect it! :)